# How to throw error into Result <T, E> without match in Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm still new to Rust.
I want to throw an error message into `Result<T, E>` and it seems to me you can't do that without `match`. In Javascript you can basically call a `callback(error, result)` anywhere in the function. What `match` is doing ? and how to propagate an error with `Result<T,E>` without `match`?

I don't like using `panic!` as it means the program will shuts off immediately when it encounters an error.

Thank you in advance.

```
use std::io::{Error, ErrorKind}; // im using std::io error here just for example

fn check(array: Vec<usize>) -> Result<bool, Error> {
    let a = array.len();
    // I need to make it error if the array.len() is 3 or above
    match a {
        3 => Ok(true), 
        _ => {
            let msg = format!("Invalid array size!");
            Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidData, msg))
        }
    }
}

fn main(){
    let a = vec!(0, 2, 3, 5);
    let result = check(a);
    let kind = result.map_err(|e| e.kind());
    println!("error kind: {:?}", kind);
}
```

This doesn't works and prints `expected "()", found enum "std::result::Result"`

```
use std::io::{Error, ErrorKind};

fn check(array: Vec<usize>) -> Result<bool, Error> {
    // if array.len() is 3 or above it throws an error
    if array.len() >= 3 { 
        let msg = format!("Invalid array size!");
        Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidData, msg))
    }
    Ok(true)
}

fn main(){
    let a = vec!(0, 2, 3, 5);
    let result = check(a);
    let kind = result.map_err(|e| e.kind());
    println!("error kind: {:?}", kind);
}
```

PLAYGROUND:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bc9c7add4d5081a591413431738a79f5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to solve your problem.

First, the issue is, that an `if` **statement** expects you to return `()` and not any other value, but an `if` **expression** can return any type, but you just have to make sure they have the same types, and you must have an `else` block.

In your example:

```rust
    if array.len() >= 3 { 
        let msg = format!("Invalid array size!");
        Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidData, msg)) 
        // ^ This is not the returned value from the function,
        // | It is returning from the if statement.
        // | If statements should have statements and not expressions.
    }
    Ok(true)
```

#### Solution 1: `return` it

```rust
    if array.len() >= 3 { 
        let msg = format!("Invalid array size!");
        return Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidData, msg));
        // ^ Returning the Err value from the function
        // | Return is a statement. Notice the semicolon
    }
    Ok(true)
```

#### Solution 2: make it an `if` expression

```rust
    if array.len() >= 3 { 
        let msg = format!("Invalid array size!");
        Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::InvalidData, msg))
    } else {
        Ok(true)
    } // Notice that all branches return the same type
```